# PrintLoop mass print all rows of data in file

Tags: excel, vba

How can I print and save all rows (pages) into a single file, rather than having to save each row as an individual PDF file. Currently the code below prints each row of data into individual PDF files.

```
Sub PrintLoop()
  Dim LR As Long, i As Long
  Application.ScreenUpdating = False

  With Sheets("Labels Data File")
    LR = .Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    For i = 2 To LR
      Sheets("Print Labels").Range("A1").Value = .Range("A" & i).Value
      Sheets("Print Labels").PrintOut
    Next i
  End With
  Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub:
```

[image]

[![enter image description here][2]][2]

I am currently trying to print the second screen shot without having to manually change the number circled red and print individual pages. I'm trying to print the whole file with one click.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Edit**

I understand your problem better now and changed my answer.  My method below is a bit of a hack and could probably be simplified greatly but works if you don't mind a few extra steps.

1. Run macro - *(This prints-to-file which defaults to your documents folder)*

   ```
   Sub PrintLoop()
     Dim LR As Long, i As Long
     Application.ScreenUpdating = False

     With Sheets("Labels Data File")
       LR = .Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
       For i = 2 To LR
         Sheets("Print Labels").Range("A1").Value = .Range("A" & i).Value
         Sheets("Print Labels").PrintOut Preview:=False, PrintToFile:=True, PrToFileName:="Lable_" & i
       Next i
     End With
     Application.ScreenUpdating = True
   End Sub
   ```
2. Combine `.prn` files into one print file

   - Open command prompt
   - Navigate to folder with `.prn` files
   - Type this: `copy *.prn combinedfile.prn`
3. Delete all `.prn` files except combinedfile.prn

   - Open command prompt
   - Navigate to folder with `.prn` files
   - Type this: `for %i in (*.prn) do if not %i == combinedfile.prn del %i`
4. Convert `.prn` file to `.pdf`
      Try using Ghost script, [see this post](https://superuser.com/a/156314/259642)

Steps 2, 3 & 4 could be setup in a batch script once you get it all working.

Comment: Thank you for the response but this seems to only pull one row of data rather than printing the rest. So what I have is a data file "Labels Data File" with all data I am pulling to another tab "Print Labels". I am trying to populate the form with this data and print each form of  data on separate pages but as one document.

Comment: Hi, Sorry my wording is not great ... I've added two screen shots on the original post. The second screen shot is the form i want to print but this form is pulling data from the first screen shot 'Labels Data File'. At the moment I am having to pull data on other rows by entering the number where I circle red and then print that individual form and repeat same process for the other rows. Hope this make it anbit clear.

Comment: No Problem, any help would be appreciated.

Comment: @Evan - I completely re-worked my answer.  Sorry it's not very straight forward and multiple steps.  Hopefully this get's you closer.  FYI, If you put steps 2,3 & 4 into a batch script, you can run that script from excel at the completion of your macro so it's hidden to the user.

Comment: Spot on that did the trick, life saver thank you for being helpful.